# Allow a single process to access a file

Tags: permissions, process, namespace

If I am the owner of a file, then is there a way I can give another process (running under another user that doesn't have read/write permission to that file) permission to access it? I want only that specific process (PID) to have access it, not any other process that has the same name as it.

Comment: Wondering if user namespaces could offer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is open the file and pass the file descriptor to the other process over a unix-domain socket using the `sendmsg` system call with [`SCM_RIGHTS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481138/how-to-use-sendmsg-to-send-a-file-descriptor-via-sockets-between-2-processes).  You can also determine what user ID is running the remote process by reading the [`SO_PEERCRED`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898961/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-uid-of-the-other-end-of-a-unix-socket-connection) socket option.  So taken together this allows you to grant control to a specific process, but it's not as transparent as just having the process open the file.